# Limit $\lim_{m\to\infty} \int_\frac1m^1\int_0^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{r^6\sin^4(a)\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)\sin^2(b)}{r^{17/2}} \,db\,da\,dr$

Tags: calculus

I need to know if the following multiple integral exist and if so, what is its value.

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \int_\frac1m^1\int_0^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{r^6\sin^4(a)\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)\sin^2(b)}{r^{17/2}} \,db\,da\,dr$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you must format your question using MathJax commands

Comment: Format your math text in LaTeX language, is this what you mean?$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{\frac{1}{m}}^{1} \frac{r^6sin^4(a)cos^2(a)cos^2(b)sin^2(b)}{r^{17/2}} \mathrm{d}b\mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}r$$

Comment: Just curious. Was this a spherical coordinates question? I had tried to find an intuitive answer (by reversing the spherical substitution and assessing the volume geometrically).

Comment: Yes, it was a spherical coordinates question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{m}}^{1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{r^6\sin^4(a)\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)\sin^2(b)}{r^{17/2}} \mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b\mathrm{d}r$$

note that you can isolate the integral on $r$

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{m}}^{1}r^{-\frac{5}{2}}\mathrm{d}r\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^4(a)\cos^2(a)\cos^2(b)\sin^2(b)\mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b$$

now you can directly integrate every term and explicitly calculate the limit.

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{m}}^{1}r^{-\frac{5}{2}}\mathrm{d}r=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} -\frac{2}{3}\left(1^{-\frac{3}{2}}-m^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)=\infty$$

Thus the integral diverges because the rest of the integral has a finite value

Comment: Your variables don't match the limits - it should be $$\int_{x_1\text{ limits}}\int_{x_2\text{ limits}}\int_{x_3\text{ limits}}\,dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1$$

Comment: Sorry, I edited it